# Wpf style ispressed property doesnt last

Tags: c#, wpf

I have styled my button when the button is clicked it would give a brushthickness of 3. Yes when i pressed it, it changes but why i doesnt last?

I mean I would like to make it stay on its pressed style.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BorderButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="ButtonBorder" >
                        </Border>

                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                        </Trigger>


                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're looking for is typical of a [ToggleButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton?view=netframework-4.7.2) or a CheckBox, not a button. Buttons are pressed only while you're holding the mouse button down over them. A CheckBox or ToggleButton toggles between two states (isChecked is true or false) when you click it.